# Prove: A nonempty subset B of a ring A is closed with respect to addition and negatives iff B is closed with respect to subtraction

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can I say something like, ∀ x,y ∈ B, x + (-y) ∈ B ⇒ x - y ∈ B by definition of subtraction?? I'm lost

Comment: That is *one* of the two directions of the "iff"

Comment: Right, I believe I would be able to take it from there if I knew at least one of the directions of the iff.

Comment: Note that since $B$ is non-empty, $\exists x\in B$. So, $x-x=0\in B$. So, $\forall x\in B, 0 - x = -x\in B$. So, $\forall x,y\in B$, $-y\in B$, so $x - (-y) = x+y\in B$.

Comment: The other direction is much more trivial.

Comment: @DonThousand your first comment was very helpful, thank you!